# O que é um código depreciado?

Tags: terminologia, deprecated

O que é um código depreciado (depreciação de código)? Ouvi falar em uma vídeo aula e fiquei em dúvida.

Comment: **Apenas para dar ênfase**, «depreciado» é a tradução errada e esta sendo mal usada e confundida com a palavra correta, «depreciado» em inglês é «depreciated» e não «deprecated». A palavra «deprecated» que seria a correta para se referir a isto seria traduzida como «obsoleto», «desaprovado», «censurado». No caso de uso aqui o melhor com certeza é «obsoleto». Resumindo «depreciado» e «depreciated» nada tem haver com isto.

Comment: código apreciado é aquele que as pessoas elogiam...e depreciado é aquele que as pessoas falam mal...rsrsrsr ou tecnicamente falando é o código que não é mais recomendado usar por existir um outro que faz a mesma coisa de uma maneira melhor ou mais segura(ou seja tem versão mais atualizada dele)

Comment: @SneepSNinjA você tem toda razão.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

O significado real para o que o termo é usado na nossa área é [**obsoleto**](https://translate.google.com/#auto/pt/deprecated), ainda que não seja a tradução exata, é o que mais deixa claro para nós. Pelo menos é considerado obsoleto pelo desenvolvedor original. Você deveria fazer o mesmo tanto quanto possível. E sempre é possível em códigos novos.

É **algo que não deve ser mais usado**. É um recurso ainda existente, mas que é considerado defasado e tem algo melhor para usar.

> ob·so·le·to |ê| (latim obsoletus, -a, -um, gasto, caído em desuso)
> adjetivo
>
> 1. Caído em desuso; que já não se usa. = ARCAICO
> 2. Que está fora de moda ou não corresponde aos últimos desenvolvimentos técnicos. = ANTIQUADO, ULTRAPASSADO ≠ .ATUAL, MODERNO
> 3. [Biologia]  Pouco desenvolvido. = ATROFIADO, RUDIMENTAR ≠ HIPERTROFIADO
>
> "obsoleto", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
> 2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/obsoleto [consultado em
> 18-01-2017].

Em inglês se usa também *obsolete*. Estritamente seria a tradução de obsoleto, mas é mais importante dizer algo que as pessoas entendem do que ter uma tradução literal.

O termo "depreciado" é tradução de *depreciated* que tem outro significado, e portanto é uma tradução errada para *deprecated*. Depreciado é algo diminuído, valor reduzido, que não é bem o caso do nosso uso, ainda que possa ser compreensível.

A não ser que o vídeo esteja falando mal de um código, aí está depreciando ele, mas se for isso não tem nada técnico no assunto :)

> de·pre·ci·ar - Conjugar verbo transitivo
>
> 1. Rebaixar o valor de. verbo transitivo e pronominal
> 2. Não dar ou não se dar o seu justo valor.
>
> "depreciado", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
> 2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/depreciado [consultado em
> 18-01-2017].

Se não gostar de obsoleto pode usar "deprecado" que é uma palavra válida no português e estritamente é a tradução mais correta. Mas que não quer dizer muita coisa para um brasileiro ou português, segundo o Jorge B. em comentário abaixo (não sei em outros países).

> de·pre·ca·do (latim deprecatus, -a, um, particípio passado de
> deprecor, -ari, procurar afastar por meio de súplicas, pedir,
> suplicar, afastar, demover, interceder, pedir perdão) adjetivo
>
> 1. [Jurídico, Jurisprudência]  Diz-se do juiz ou tribunal a que um juiz ou tribunal mandou deprecada ou pedido de .ato ou diligência.
> 2. [Informática]  Cuja utilização já não se recomenda (ex.: esta função não está obsoleta, mas está deprecada).
>
> "deprecado", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
> 2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/deprecado [consultado em
> 18-01-2017].

## Uso em linguagens

Isso não é algo específico do PHP. Sempre que ver essa marcação em alguma documentação, não use, procure saber o que deve usar no lugar. Há páginas de cada versão indicando o que foi deprecado. [Exemplo na 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php). Quando não há substituto, é porque não deve usar nada, aquilo é ruim por si só.

É comum elas gerarem um *warning*. E *warnings* deveriam ser tratados como erros, sempre. O que está obsoleto um dia pode deixar de existir.

Há quem diga que deprecado é o que ficará obsoleto, e obsoleto é o que foi retirado. Isso não faz sentido, afinal o que foi retirado não é mais obsoleto, é não existente. O que não existe não pode ser chamado de deprecado ou obsoleto. Nesse caso se for citar o que existia  e não existe mais, o termo deveria ser "removido" ou algo que passe essa ideia.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Em Portugal deprecado também não quer dizer nada, ou usamos «deprecated» ou «obsoleto».

Comment: « O termo depreciado é tradução de depreciated que tem outro significado, e portanto é uma tradução errada para deprecated.» A unica resposta correta de fato é a sua +1. Estranhamente a resposta errada ganhou mais pontos http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/178139/3635, acho que o povo anda dando upvotes sem ter certeza/sem confirmar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento a pergunta talvez seja mais referente ao que significa em termos práticos, e não a origem etimológica do termo/melhor tradução. A melhor resposta ao OP teria que ser neste sentido, eu acho, dentro do contexto de desenvolvimento de software: o que significa e o que fazer quando se deparar com esse termo, que é o que importa, afinal.

Comment: @mrlew não, «depreciado» foi erro de tradução da palavra «deprecated», por um claro engano devido a semelhança, não é questão de termos práticos ou etimológica, é apenas confusão/erro mesmo. ;)

Comment: O que se refere o termo está na minha resposta e outras. A pergunta usa o termo errado, que deve ter sido usado errado na tal da vídeo aula (ah vá que vídeo aula de PHP fala coisa errada? :) ). Por isso a minha resposta tentou desmistificar isso.

Comment: Vou chutar aqui que deprecado vem de demover para um estado precário. Isso pode ser assunto para o http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @bigown parece bem provável, estado precário.

Answer (score 10):

O status *deprecated* (abaixo falo sobre a tradução em português) é aplicado normalmente a uma funcionalidade (*feature*), função, ou qualquer encapsulamento de código que **não está mais sendo suportado oficialmente pelo seu desenvolvedor** (aqui considerando pessoa física ou empresa, responsável pela edição das versões oficiais do software - normalmente o autor).

Isto significa, em outras palavras, que o desenvolvedor **desencoraja** o uso deste código, em que pese ele ainda não ter sido removido do código fonte.

Ocorre normalmente quando o desenvolvedor optou por não evoluir mais aquele código (seja qual for a razão - segurança, performance, código mal escrito), e normalmente apresenta uma nova alternativa para a solução do mesmo problema que aquela função resolvia anteriormente.

A mensagem é de **desencorajamento** quanto ao uso, que **não significa que o uso é proibido**. É um passo para o código ser removido no futuro e normalmente a mensagem é algo como: *"esta funcionalidade foi desencorajada e será removida nas futuras versões"*.

Esta técnica é amplamente utilizada e serve principalmente para **manter  compatibilidade**. Imagine se um desenvolvedor, por exemplo, descobre que uma funcionalidade causa problemas de performance em um cenário específico e decide simplesmente remover o código, substituindo por outro, incompatível com as versões atuais. Isto quebraria várias aplicações que o utilizam. O caminho recomendado é desencorajar o uso do código, sinalizar aos usuários que o código não é mais recomendado (e que será removido nas próximas versões), e cabe aos usuários, neste período, providenciarem a atualização das suas aplicações.

Na prática, então, o melhor é sempre evitar código com este *status*, pois certamente tiveram razões para ele ter sido marcado como *deprecated*. Procure adaptar-se sempre à alternativa trazida pelo desenvolvedor.

---

### Exemplo

Um exemplo clássico no PHP (mencionei em PHP por que foi uma das tags da sua pergunta) foi a função [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), que teve seu uso desencorajado na versão 5.5 e definitivamente removida na versão 7, por questões de segurança, principalmente ([motivos](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation)).

---

### Sobre o termo e a tradução

Em que pese ser utilizado pela comunidade de desenvolvedores brasileiros, ***"depreciado"*** não é a tradução do inglês *deprecated*. Alguns sustentam, por outro lado, que a melhor tradução seria **obsoleto**, ou até mesmo **deprecado**.

Apesar de ser apenas uma simples questão de terminologia, deixo aqui minhas humildes considerações:

Primeiro de tudo, creio que **obsoleto** não seria a melhor tradução (em que pese ser a tradução literal para o google), ao meu ver, pois um código marcado como depreciado não significa necessariamente que ele se tornará instantaneamente obsoleto. *Cair em desuso* seria quando, voluntariamente, a comunidade deixa de usar, ou seja, um código que deixou de ser útil ao passar do tempo. O que nem sempre é o caso. Também neste sentido não seria *fora de moda*, *arcaico*. Um código que teve seu uso desencorajado não é necessariamente arcaico ou moderno.

Podemos ter um código super popular, mas, por alguma questão de segurança, por exemplo, o autor informou que será depreciado. Depreciar um código, às vezes, é um processo totalmente inverso, de forçar o código a deixar de ser popular.

O que quero dizer é que, por definição etimológica, algo não pode ser tornado "obsoleto" por alguém, pois *cair em desuso* é um processo natural. Depreciar é algo como "querer que ele seja obsoleto". Tornar o código depreciado é torcer para que ele caia em desuso. Se não cair, e continuar popular, muitas aplicações vão quebrar quando ele for removido. Este é o meu ponto.

Prosseguindo. Pesquisando o termo original, percebi que os dicionários  da língua inglesa descrevem *deprecate* como *"to not approve of something"* (cambridge), *"to express earnest disapproval of"* (dictionary.com) ou seja,  seria algo como **desaprovar**. Percebe-se que não tem relação com antiquado.

Penso que, quando se importou o termo *deprecate* para o desenvolvimento de software, o que se quis dizer foi simplesmente: "desaprovar o uso", no sentido teleológico de "desencorajar".

Já o termo **depreciar** (que seria a tradução de *depreciate*, outra coisa) signfica, pelo Michaelis: *reduzir o valor*, *desvalorizar*. Se nós formos considerar que aplicar um status de *deprecated* a um código significa dar um valor menor a ele, relativo aos demais, pode ser uma assertiva válida. Por exemplo, se uma função é mantida, testada, corrigida, melhorada, refatorada, ela possui um valor de suportada, em desenvolvimento, oficial. Já aquela função que nem está no mapa dos testes, "marcada para sumir", certamente possui um valor menor na visão do desenvolvedor.

Mas, concordo que ainda assim não é uma tradução para *deprecate*.

À título de conclusão, feitas estas considerações, minha opinião é que não há uma tradução correspondente para este term, pois parece não haver um *match* em português (o termo foi de propósito rsrs).

E, indo além, talvez este seja um dos casos que o melhor mesmo é falar em inglês no meio da frase em português para se fazer entender. Sem a consciência pesada. Ou usar o **deprecado**, que parece ser a melhor alternativa.

**ATUALIZADO**

Depois de escrever o texto acima, fiz algumas busca no SOEn, e encontrei alguns tópicos como este [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208091/the-difference-between-deprecated-depreciated-and-obsolete), em que alguns sustentam que há diferença entre *obsolete* (deixou de ser usado) e *deprecated* (está em uso, mas será removido), sendo que alguém até citou uma relação: *"Something is depreciated until it is obsolete."*. Apenas para ilustrar.

Answer (score 7):

**Depreciado** é uma possível tradução de *Depreciated*, que se assemelha a *Deprecated* que quer dizer **obsoleto** (que seria o mais usado na área de programação). Como usamos essa palavra mais no linguajar econômico, ficamos desacostumados com esse sentido e as vezes, concordo, fica até estranho.

> Obsoleto significa tudo aquilo que está ultrapassado, fora de uso,
>   antiquado, arcaico. Obsoleto também é usado na referência a coisas que
>   com o passar do tempo vão sendo substituídas, e isto ocorre com uma
>   frequência muito grande em função da tecnologia que está cada vez mais
>   avançada.

Quando usamos depreciado em português passamos a ideia de algo que perdeu o valor. *Depreciated* não quer dizer que o método perdeu o valor ou sofreu depreciação, mas sim que ele não é mais a forma aprovada de fazer algo.

Particularmente, prefiro o termo "desuso" (o método `maeDaFoca()` está em "desuso"), pois desuso significa "o que não está mais em uso", que é justamente a ideia do *deprecated*: de, se possível, não usar mais este método, pois ele será removido ou deixará de funcionar.

Um exemplo deste tipo de método, é você verificar a classe [`java.util.Date()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) da versão 1.6 do Java. [`.getDay()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDay()), por exemplo.

Referências

- [Significado de Obsoleto](https://www.significados.com.br/obsoleto/)

Comment: Esta correto agora, mas realmente eu daria melhor enfase em explicar que ambas nada tem haver e o significado de cada uma ;)

Answer (score 1):

Depreciação geralmente é quando entrou em desuso, onde em novas versões  foi ou será descontinuado. Onde surgem algo novo para a substituir. Mas sobre o que exatamente ouviu falar?

Comment: Não é não, depreciado em inglês é `Depreciated` e **não** `Deprecated`.

Answer (score 1):

É algum recurso que ainda está presente em uma linguagem/framework, mas que será retirado na próxima versão.

Então, nesse caso cabe ao programador utilizar com cautela, sabendo que se fizer isso vai impedir que o código rode em versões futuras.

Lembrando que geralmente tem algo para substituir. Sendo quase sempre uma péssima ideia optar por utilizar algo nessas condições.

Comment: Não é não, depreciado em inglês é `Depreciated` e **não** `Deprecated`.