# Por que a opção "salt" do password_hash foi descontinuado no PHP 7?

Tags: php, php-7

Estou recebendo o erro ao tentar fazer o seguinte teste:

```
[
 "salt" => "um salt grandão de responsa",
 "cost" => 12,
]

password_hash (123456, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);
```

Está retornando:

> Use of the 'salt' option to password_hash is deprecated

Por que a opção `salt` é considerada obsoleta?

Comment: Segundo a resposta mais votada [dessa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178138/101) ela pode até ter sido inicialmente depreciada, mas o que importa pra gente é que ela foi deprecada :P

Comment: Basicamente por que boa parte do pessoal do PHP não faz a mínima idéia do que está fazendo, e em vez de usar o _salt_ como deviam, estragavam a segurança usando outros campos ou valor fixo no lugar. Se tem gente que faz coisas absurdas como salvar base64 no DB, usa `addslashes` pra sanitizar MySQL, imagine o resto...

Comment: @Bacco eu escrevo sempre "depreciado". "Deprecado" acho feio pra caramba.

Comment: O termo mais adequado é "Obsoleto". Depreciado é mais ligado a valores monetários. E deprecada é um termo usado pelo ramo do direito, onde se refere a algum juiz que recebeu uma ordem para cumprir determinado serviço judicial. Sobre a questão, bom, eu acredito que o PHP está seguindo normas da organização mundial de saúde, que recomenda diminuir o sal (rsrs, brincadeiras à parte). O PHP aboliu a opção Salt pois ele acredita ser mais interessante usar o gerador de salt interno da função.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Porque o `salt` deve ser único para cada senha, permitir definir um `salt` poderia fazer com que definisse um `salt` constante.

Por exemplo:

```
password_hash('senha_legal', PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['salt' => '1234567891234567891234']);
```

Dessa forma todas as senhas utilizariam `1234567891234567891234`, todas as senhas iriam sair da seguinte forma:

```
$2y$10$123456789123456789123u2l31KVtAAQPjgDEYorAjG5V8p9MWDx2
$2y$10$123456789123456789123uOlCRXcGHP2s7.4hwA7pLsVlmqL3pmLq
$2y$10$123456789123456789123uN0gdQ.iBssxH4MxYvSqqYkSgAKQuL9S
```

O uso do `salt` faz com que um senha comum se torne incomum, por isso se um usuário cadastrar com a mesma senha, usando o mesmo salt iria resultar:

```
$2y$10$123456789123456789123uN0gdQ.iBssxH4MxYvSqqYkSgAKQuL9S
```

Não importa quantas vezes você fizer um `php -r "echo password_hash('senha_legal', PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['salt' => '1234567891234567891234']);"` o resultado sempre será esse, independe de onde, do tempo ou do servidor.

Um atacante irá ter a senha de dois usuários, porque todos os usuários que usarem a senha `senha_legal` terá o mesmo resultado, *além disso ele poderá ter a capacidade de gerar várias senhas utilizando o mesmo `salt` e assim verificar se as senhas coincidem diretamente.*

Exemplos usados:

```
123 => $2y$10$123456789123456789123u2l31KVtAAQPjgDEYorAjG5V8p9MWDx2
teste => $2y$10$123456789123456789123uOlCRXcGHP2s7.4hwA7pLsVlmqL3pmLq
senha_legal  => $2y$10$123456789123456789123uN0gdQ.iBssxH4MxYvSqqYkSgAKQuL9S
```

O que faz as senhas serem diferentes é o `salt` aplicado a ela, e como pode perceber o `salt` está presente no código acima, pela constante de `123456789123456789123`, com o `$10` indicando sua dificuldade.

Comment: Muito bom, muito bom. As vezes eu só acho chato o PHP tomar medidas anti programadores sobrinhos. Acho que cada um deve se responsabilizar por suas escolhas :p

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Mas isso é bom, não é apenas uma medida 'anti-sobrinhos', é uma melhoria de segurança, uma preocupação a menos para o programador, para poder se concentrar no que realmente importa, em resolver o problema na sua frente sem precisar se preocupar com os mesmos detalhes sempre.

Answer (score 2):

Questão de segurança, é mais seguro utilizar um salt aleatório.

Agora a própria função gera um salt aleatório sempre que for chamada, antes era possível impedir isso passando um salt estático menos seguro.

Fonte: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php