# Bcrypt em java e php não corresponde

Tags: php, java, bcrypt

Eu tenho uma aplicação em Php que faz um registo de uma pessoa e quando a pessoa poe a password, a password fica armazenada na base de dados em forma de hash, com o seguinte código

```
password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)
```

depois, tenho uma aplicação em Java e queria verificar uma password com a hash que está na base de dados, eu pus o seguinte código

```
BCrypt.hashpw(passTxt.getText(),BCrypt.gensalt())
```

o problema é que não correspondem as hashes. já me disseram que pode ser do SALT que tem que ser o mesmo, mas como faço para por o mesmo SALT?

Comment: Aqui [nesse link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/179761/57801) tem um exemplo de utilização, mas já verifique que o SALT está obsoleto na versão 7

Comment: sim, mas como faço no Java a verificação da hash ser o mesmo que no php?

Answer (score 0):

em PHP

```
<?php
 /**
 * Note that the salt here is randomly generated.
 * Never use a static salt or one that is not randomly generated.
 *
 * For the VAST majority of use-cases, let password_hash generate the salt randomly for you
 */
    $options = [
        'cost' => 11,
        'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM),
    ];
echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options)."\n";
?>
```

Em Java [jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/)

```
// Hash a password for the first time
String hashed = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt());

// gensalt's log_rounds parameter determines the complexity
// the work factor is 2**log_rounds, and the default is 10
String hashed = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt(12));

// Check that an unencrypted password matches one that has
// previously been hashed
if (BCrypt.checkpw(candidate, hashed))
    System.out.println("It matches");
else
    System.out.println("It does not match");
```

pode ser o salt diferente então estou colocando como mudar o salt dos 2.

fonte [stack inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953553/how-to-have-the-same-password-compatible-with-both-java-and-php)

O bcrypt normal não vai resultar o que você busca nativamente mas a jBcrypt pode lhe trazer olhar o stack em ingles lhe traz o resto da resposta.