# Como colocar imagem no input type reset?

Tags: php, javascript, html

É possível colocar uma imagem no input com o

> type="image"

Mas ele fica como submit e eu quero deixar o

> input type="reset"

Com imagem também mas sem ficar como submit e sim para dar um reset nas informações digitadas pelo usuário no formulário, é possível ?

Segue abaixo meu arquivo PHP:

```
<input type="image" src="imagens/imagem.png" />
<input type="reset" value="Cancelar">
```

Meu arquivo JS está fazio.

Comment: Pode esconder o input e estilizar um label que possui o atributo `for` apontado para o input.

Comment: O problema é fazer isso amigo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Usando `Label`

Quase todos os controles de form podem ter um "atalho" com um label:

```css
#r {display:none}
#l {
  display:block;
  width:32px;
  height:32px;
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OV6nj.jpg?s=32)
}
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
  <input id="r" type="reset">
  <label id="l" for="r"></label>
</form>
```

Isto funciona para estilizar *checkbox*, *radiobutton*, e muitos outros controles. O `label` é um ótimo aliado do CSS.

Lembre-se que a estilização é um exemplo, se quiser manter o fluxo igual o botão original, pode usar `inline-block` em vez de `block`.

Além disso, se não quiser por a imagem pelo CSS, pode simplesmente por o `img` dentro do `label`. Usualmente é mais interessante deixar no CSS, por ser estilização, e não conteúdo.

### Estilizando o `input`

Dependendo do nível de compatibilidade desejado, basta estilizar com CSS:

```css
#r {
  display:block;
  border:none;
  width:32px;
  height:32px;
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OV6nj.jpg?s=32)
}
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
  <input id="r" type="reset" value="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Você também pode tentar trocar por `<button>`, veja o exemplo abaixo, digite qualquer coisa no `textarea` e depois aperte o botão:

```html
<form>
<textarea cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
<button type="reset">
    <img src="imagens/imagem.png">
</button>
</form>
```

E se não gosta do formato do botão e só quer deixar a imagem pode usar css:

```css
.custom-btn {
    border:none; /*remove as bordas*/
    padding: 0; /*remove os espaços*/
    background-color: transparent; /*remove o fundo cinza*/

    /*remove a aparência customizada/nativa do navegador*/
    -webkit-appearance: none;
       -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
<textarea cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
<button class="custom-btn" type="reset">
    <img src="imagens/imagem.png">
</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode deixar o `value` em branco pra não ir texto no `input` e colocar uma imagem de fundo por *css*.

`background-size: cover` indica que é para a imagem obter o espaço total do elemento.

### Exemplo:

```css
input[type=reset] {
  background: url('http://www.intranet.jmrc.co.in/Jaipur-Metro/images/Refresh.png');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" />
  <input id="resetar" type="reset" value=""></input>
</form>
```

Comment: Quando deixo "value" em branco ele some tudo e não aparece nada nem imagem, quando não deixo ele aparece a imagem só que dentro do botão com o nome por baixo.

Comment: Pode fazer um Fiddle da forma que esta fazendo @LoneTonberry?

Comment: No meu arquivo PHP eu dei um ID da mesma forma como você fez ai.No meu arquivo CSS eu puxei esse id ficando da seguinte maneira: #resetar{
  background-image: url(../imagens/cadeiraPreta.png);
  background-size: cover;
}.Editei a pergunta com o meu arquivo PHP

Answer (score 1):

Os inputs realmente são chatos de personalizar... Eu mesmo ontem estava me vendo para personalizar alguns inputs e o select... Mas consegui!
Respondendo a sua pergunta, eu vejo duas formas de resolver seu problema.

**Primeira**
Você pode colocar um input image e um input type reset. No input type reset coloca opacity 0 e no src do type img coloca a imagem e então coloque o onclick e chama a função js que clica no input type reset.

**Segunda**
Você pode também criar um input type img (no src põe a imagem) e colocar no onclick para ele resetar os valores direto. Eu tenho um código aqui que eu já usei para uns e pode ser interessante para ti.

```
/* Ao clicar no input type image, clique no reset */
<input type="reset" id="reset" style="opacity: 0;">
<input type="image" src="resetbtn.png" onclick="resetClick()">
<script>
 function resetClick(){
document.getElementById("reset").click();
}</script>

/* Ao clicar no input image reseta os valores dos inputs do formulário */ 







    <html><head><script>
    function resetClick(){
      clearRadioGroup('radioinput');
      clearInputUrlNumberText('textinput');
      clearInputUrlNumberText('numberinput');
     clearInputUrlNumberText('urlinput');
     confereChecado('checkbox');
    }

     /* Confere checkbox */ 
 function confereChecado(id){
var checked = document.getElementById(id).checked;
if(checked == true){
    document.getElementById(id).click();
}
if(checked == false){}}

 /* Função da Ação de Resetar Text, Numbers, Url Inputs */
 function clearInputUrlNumberText(name){
var entradas = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='"+name+"']");
[].map.call(entradas, entrada => entrada.value = '');
}


 /* Função da Ação de Resetar Radio Input */
 function clearRadioGroup(GroupName){
var ele = document.getElementsByName(GroupName);
for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
ele[i].checked = false;
}

    </script>
    <style></style>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="">
    <input id="radiouno" type="radio" name="radioinput" value="opt1">opt1
    <input id="radioduo" type="radio" name="radioinput" value="opt2">opt2
    <input id="text" type="text" name="textinput">text
    <input id="number" type="number" name="numberinput">number
    <input id="url" type="url" name="urlinput">url
    <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkboxinput">checkbox
    <input id="reset" type="image" src="img/reset.png" onclick="resetClick()">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Eu estava tentando fazer desse segunda forma só que meus conhecimentos são poucos e fiquei na dúvida de como fazer pra o JS resetar as informações digitadas no formulário.A função que faz com que seja resetada as informações estão na sua resposta ?

Comment: Sim, eu procurei listar os inputs mais comuns no formulário e a forma de resetá-lo. Eu também sou meio novo no js, mas uma dica que sempre funcionou pra mim é antes de colocar no projeto fazer uma página html normal e testar. Lone, pela segunda forma coloca no onclick o nome da sua função sem esquecer dos parênteses (ex: minhaFuncao() ) e coloca essas funções que te passei para resetar dependendo do tipo de input dentro! Entendeu? Você pode passar o seu código também pra eu fazer!

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta.Mas não to entendendo qual dessas funções eu devo colocar na tag input.E como deve ficar o onClick nessa tag?

Comment: Olha lá eu editei a resposta. Lone, no onclick você coloca a função que criou acompanhada do parênteses (e se tiver criado parâmetros, dentro dele). No <script> você coloca as três funções para apagar inputs e dentro da função que você criou e escreveu no onclick coloca as funções sem precisar descrevê-las, apenas com o name dos inputs ou com a id da checkbox dentro dos parênteses!

Comment: Não use o appearance no CSS que ele está depreciado!

Comment: Aqui tem o suporte do appearance. http://caniuse.com/#search=appearance - falando assim, vai acabar depreciando ele, coitado kkk

Comment: eu sei da existência moz, tals

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_appearance.asp mas olha isso, direto da W3 - repare no título da página! ser aceito é diferente de atual!

Comment: Mais uma coisa pra vc saber, w3schools não tem nadinha a ver com w3. Inclusive era conhecido como "w3fools". É legal ajudar, mas se puser uns links de confiança, valoriza um bocado o comentário.

Comment: @GiancarloSolderaGraziano não é depreciado, depreciado significa outra coisa [acesse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178138/o-que-é-um-código-depreciado#comment368172_178138) e mais um detalhe `appearance` não é obsoleto, não sei de onde tirou tal informação, você deve ter confundido com os prefixos e nem os prefixos são obsoletos, eles são apenas `non-standards` então leia https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance e por favor antes de falar algo tenha certeza da informação ;)

Comment: posso ter me expressado errado guilherme, bacco tb Mas o que eu quis dizer é que não vale a pena usar uma propriedade que não é mais usada e que tem que ficar usando webkits (no css4 provavelmente não terá). E também, mesmo que eu tenha achado um pouco grosseiro a maneira que vocês falaram eu li vários tópicos sobre ela e decidi não usá-la no meu último projeto...

Comment: @GiancarloSolderaGraziano concordo com você quanto ao uso, se pareceu grosseiro não foi a intenção, mas como você comentou sobre o assunto, a gente veiro aqui pra acrescentar e melhorar se possível a explicação, assim todo mundo aprende. Como eu disse antes, acho legal você estar gastando seu tempo pra vir aqui ajudar, isso conta muito. As dicas são só para melhorar a eficiência da ajuda. Se algo pareceu grosseiro, realmente não foi o objetivo.

Comment: Se foi pq eu falei de w3fools, não foi ironia não, é que realmente aconteceu: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @GiancarloSolderaGraziano talvez `appearance:` tenha sido removido (não achei informação alguma sobre isso no w3.org), mas mesmo assim os com prefixo são `non-standards` (não padrões) e podem ser usados, já que eles funcionam para navegadores (motores na verdade) específicos. Fora que se não tiver no tal CSS4 (se sua informação for correta) é porque não vai mais precisar e o `appearance: ...;` não vai ter efeito algum, só servirá de retro-compatibilidade para navegadores que ainda não usem CSS4 (no futuro)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento a própria MDN já avisa pra não usar, pq cada browser faz de um jeito, mas é como vc disse, prefixado ela é critério do vendor do browser. Quanto à recomendação de não usar, acho que todos nós estamos de acordo que não é boa idéia mesmo.

Comment: @Bacco não usar quando se refere a depender daquilo, o estilo ali não depende, na verdade nem é necessário, mas em alguns smartphones sem ele fica estranho (exemplo o iOS que eu uso inclusive). E se vierem a remover aquilo lá não afetará, apenas não será reconhecido, servirá como uma "retro-compatibilidade" (usei a palavra certo?) para que teu site funcione em dispositivos mais antigos.