# Tela branca em login do wordpress

Tags: wordpress, login

Ao tentar fazer o login em meu site wordpress a tela fica toda branca, pesquisei na net e testei algumas possíveis soluções:

Aumentei a memória para o wordpress ( não era esse o problema)

Renomeei a pasta plugin para plugin_old e criei uma nova pasta plugin, e também fiz isso em plugin por plugin ( não era esse o problema)

Vi que também pode ser o tema, renomeei o nome da pasta do meu plugin ativo e segundo li, o wordpress retornaria meu site para o tema padrão mas oq aconteceu foi que o site todo agora ficou branco.

Dei um debug no wp-config e todos os problemas que aparecem na tela de fazer o login são relacionados ao widget "O método construtor chamado para WP_Widget em mad_widget_social_links esta depreciado desde a versão 4.3.0! Utilize
__construct()", mas eu não encontro de jeito nenhum onde está essa chamada para que eu possa alterar. Acredito que possa estar no  tema mesmo mas não encontro. Lembrando que ao colocar o debug não aparece mais o local para fazer o login no site portanto eu não consigo ir para a tela que ficava branca anteriormente e ver se la aparece outro tipo de erro.

Comment: com o WP_DEBUG ligado voce não consegue entrar na sua URL? Você tentou entrar direto em {urldosite.com.br}/wp-admin ?

Comment: eu entro no wp-admin, coloco o user se senha e ele me redireciona para a page wp-login.php que está em branco. Reinstalei o wordpress para ir testando a cada passo que iria adicionando algo mas mesmo com o wordpress cru está com esse problema e não aparece nenhum erro no debug e o arquivo de erros do php está em branco.

Comment: Qual versão do Wordpress você está usando?

Comment: Apenas uma nota sobre o uso da palavra: [**«depreciado» em inglês é «depreciated» e não «deprecated». A palavra «deprecated» que seria a correta para se referir a isto seria traduzida como «obsoleto», «desaprovado», «censurado»**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178138/3635)