# Ocultar colunas de tabela ao redimensionar pagina html

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Tenho uma tabela html:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando redimensiono a página para uma resolução menor gostaria que ficasse apenas 2 colunas e quando voltasse para resolução maior ficasse com as 5 colunas. Uso bootstrap.
Poderia ser em javascript também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você queria fazer mesmo somente com `bootstrap` ou `JavaScript`? Apenas com `CSS` puro você consegue fazer isso. Segue exemplo:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 442px) {
  table th:nth-child(3) {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 442px) {
  table th:nth-child(4) {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 442px) {
  table th:nth-child(5) {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 442px) {
  table td:nth-child(3) {
     display: inline;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 442px) {
  table td:nth-child(4) {
    display: inline;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 442px) {
  table td:nth-child(5) {
     display: inline;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td>
    Coluna 1
  </td>
  <td>
    Coluna 2
  </td>
  <td>
    Coluna 3
  </td>
  <td>
    Coluna 4
  </td>
  <td>
    Coluna 5
  </td>
</table>
```

Nesse exemplo, quando a resolução da tela possuir largura menor ou igual a 442px serão ocultadas as 3 últimas colunas e, quando a resolução possuir largura maior que 442px as 3 últimas colunas serão exibidas.

Segue também exemplo utilizando JavaScript:

```js
$( window ).resize(function() {
  var largura = $(window).width();
  if (largura < 442){
      $('table td:nth-child(3)').css("display", "none");
      $('table td:nth-child(4)').css("display", "none");
      $('table td:nth-child(5)').css("display", "none");
  }
  else{
      $('table td:nth-child(3)').css("display", "inline");
      $('table td:nth-child(4)').css("display", "inline");
      $('table td:nth-child(5)').css("display", "inline");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <td>
    Coluna 1
  </td>
  <td>
    Coluna 2
  </td>
  <td>
    Coluna 3
  </td>
  <td>
    Coluna 4
  </td>
  <td>
    Coluna 5
  </td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Existem classes próprias do bootstrap para esse comportamento. No seu caso, sugiro a combinação das classes `.visible-md-block` e `.visible-lg-block`, adicione elas nos elementos que tu quer esconder em uma resolução no menor.

Segue a lista de classes e seus respectivos comportamentos: [Bootstrap - Responsive Utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities).

> As classes `.visible-xs`, `.visible-sm`, `.visible-md`, and `.visible-lg` estão **obsoletas** a partir da **versão 3.2.0**.

---

Ou você pode utilizar media queries para isso, aconselho criar uma classe nova e trabalhar nela, evitando conflitos com o bootstrap:

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  .classe-nova{
     display:none;
   }
}
```

Comment: Apenas uma nota sobre o uso da palavra: [**«depreciado» em inglês é «depreciated» e não «deprecated». A palavra «deprecated» que seria a correta para se referir a isto seria traduzida como «obsoleto», «desaprovado», «censurado»**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178138/3635)