# removeAttr('required') obsoleto?

Tags: jquery

Possuo a seguinte linha no meu código:

```
$('#infs').removeAttr('required');
```

E ao utilizar o plugin [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate), obtenho o seguinte *warning* no debug:

> JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.removeAttr no longer sets boolean properties:
>   required

Comment: [«depreciado» em inglês é «depreciated» e não «deprecated». A palavra «deprecated» que seria a correta para se referir a isto seria traduzida como «obsoleto», «desaprovado», «censurado»](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178138/3635)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acordo com a [página de *warnings*](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md) do plugin jQuery Migrate 3.0+

> **JQMIGRATE: `jQuery.fn.removeAttr` não define mais propriedades booleanas**
>
> **Causa:** Antes do jQuery 3.0, o uso de `.removeAttr()` em um atributo
>   booleano, como `checked`, `selected` ou `readonly` também definiria a
>   propriedade correspondente como falsa. Esse comportamento era
>   necessário para versões antigas do Internet Explorer, mas não é
>   correto para navegadores modernos porque o atributo representa o valor
>   inicial e a propriedade representa o valor atual (dinâmico).
>
> **Solução:** quase sempre é errado usar `.removeAttr("checked")` em um
>   elemento do DOM. A única vez que pode ser útil é se o DOM for
>   posteriormente serializado de volta para uma string HTML. Em todos
>   os outros casos, deve ser usado `.prop("checked", false)`.

Portanto, o código abaixo deve resolver:

```
$('#infs').prop('required', false);
```