# Em PHP, existe diferença entre Double e Float?

Tags: php, float, double

Em algumas linguagens de programação, Float e Double, apesar de parecidos, não são a mesma coisa. Porém aparentemente no PHP não há diferença entre esses dois tipos.

Existe alguma razão especial para isso? Porque o cast de Double e Float resultam na mesma coisa?

```
 gettype( (double) '1.66' ); // double

 gettype( (float) '1.66' ); // double

 is_double(1.66); // true

 is_float(1.66); // true
```

Comment: Não existe de facto diferença nos três. [Questão relacionada no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280892/difference-between-float-and-double-in-php)

Comment: Esqueceu da pergunta ou ainda não achou a resposta que queria? hahaha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Existe diferença entre Double e Float ou Real?

Não, não existe diferença alguma entre o `double`, `float` ou `real` no php.

> Existe alguma razão especial para isso?

Sim! Praticidade e para simplificar as coisas também. Em `C`, que é onde o PHP é feito, as variáveis são armazenadas em uma estrutura, que consiste em uma união entre vários tipos de dados que a variável poderia armazenar, como `boolean`, `string`, `int`, e `double`, que é como é armazenado todos os valores com casas decimais, independente se ele foi considerado `double`, `float` ou `real`, no php.

Você pode ver mais sobre isso [aqui](https://devzone.zend.com/317/extension-writing-part-ii-parameters-arrays-and-zvals/).

> Porque o cast de Double e Float resultam na mesma coisa?

Como eu disse na resposta acima, por trás dos panos (em `C`), tudo acaba sendo transformado em `double`.

Answer (score 5):

Para completar a [resposta do Francisco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/226831/5878), é válido colocar o código fonte em C da implementação do PHP. Por exemplo, ao utilizar a função [`settype`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.settype.php), a documentação recomenda:

> Os valores possíveis para type são:
>
> - "float" (somente para versões acima do PHP 4.2.0, para versões antigas use a variação depreciada "double")

Ou seja, você precisará definir como `float` ao invés de `double`, mas verificando a implementação da função, temos:

```
/* {{{ proto bool settype(mixed &var, string type)
   Set the type of the variable */
PHP_FUNCTION(settype)
{
    zval *var;
    char *type;
    size_t type_len = 0;

    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_START(2, 2)
        Z_PARAM_ZVAL_DEREF(var)
        Z_PARAM_STRING(type, type_len)
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_END();

    if (!strcasecmp(type, "integer")) {
        convert_to_long(var);
    } else if (!strcasecmp(type, "int")) {
        convert_to_long(var);
    } else if (!strcasecmp(type, "float")) {
        convert_to_double(var);
    } else if (!strcasecmp(type, "double")) { /* deprecated */
        convert_to_double(var);
    } else if (!strcasecmp(type, "string")) {
        convert_to_string(var);
    } else if (!strcasecmp(type, "array")) {
        convert_to_array(var);
    } else if (!strcasecmp(type, "object")) {
        convert_to_object(var);
    } else if (!strcasecmp(type, "bool")) {
        convert_to_boolean(var);
    } else if (!strcasecmp(type, "boolean")) {
        convert_to_boolean(var);
    } else if (!strcasecmp(type, "null")) {
        convert_to_null(var);
    } else if (!strcasecmp(type, "resource")) {
        php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "Cannot convert to resource type");
        RETURN_FALSE;
    } else {
        php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "Invalid type");
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }
    RETVAL_TRUE;
}
/* }}} */
```

Onde destaca-se as linhas:

```
} else if (!strcasecmp(type, "float")) {
    convert_to_double(var);
}
```

Se o tipo for `float`, converte o valor para `double`. E o tipo definido como `double` foi tornado obsoleto sabe-se lá porquê (a buscar a informação no *changelog*).

O mesmo ocorre com a função [`floatval`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.floatval.php):

```
/* {{{ proto float floatval(mixed var)
   Get the float value of a variable */
PHP_FUNCTION(floatval)
{
    zval *num;

    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_START(1, 1)
        Z_PARAM_ZVAL(num)
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_END();

    RETURN_DOUBLE(zval_get_double(num));
}
/* }}} */
```

Retornando o próprio tipo `double`.

> O arquivo fonte completo pode ser visto no [repositório oficial da linguagem](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/9c2a1f52a5f087c70a9e91dc1f43e5718d1bd8b6/ext/standard/type.c).

Comment: Muito boa resposta. Porque será que deixaram de utilizar o `float` ? Intrigante...

Comment: @Isac várias coisas no PHP dá pra fazer muitas teorias da conspiração, hahaha.

Comment: Por este motivo eu nunca pego links de docs em português, apenas uma nota sobre o uso da palavra: [**«depreciado» em inglês é «depreciated» e não «deprecated». A palavra «deprecated» que seria a correta para se referir a isto seria traduzida como «obsoleto», «desaprovado», «censurado»**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178138/3635)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento de fato, só mantive o termo por estar presente na documentação e não correr o risco de gerar confusão.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss a tradução é comunitária e não necessariamente feita por pessoas da equipe, até mesmo eu e você podemos editar. ;)