# Passar a variável GET por mais de uma página

Tags: php, javascript, html

Passo duas variáveis via GET para uma pagina com uma condição PHP, onde extraio uma nova variavel que devo enviar para uma segunda pagina, porém para esta segunda pagina deveria ir as 3 variáveis mas está enviando apenas a ultima.

Segue o código melhor explicado.

```
<form class="got" method="GET" action="real_time.qm.php">
                <select name="papel">
<?php
//Recebo as variaveis da outra pagina
$loc = $_GET['loc'];
$ori = $_GET['ori'];

include ("Conectcma.php");

        $pl = "SELECT Papel FROM reg_qm_papel WHERE Local = '$loc' AND origem = '$ori'";
        $plgo = mysqli_query($conexao, $pl);

    while($sc_l = mysqli_fetch_array($plgo)){
       echo '<option>'.$sc_l['Papel'].'</option>';
   }
?>
</select>
<br>
     <br>
     <br>
     <!-- Ao clicar no botão, deveria retornar as 3 variaveis($_GET['loc'],$_GET['ori'] e papel) porém, só retorna a ultima -->
   <button class="css_btn_class" type="submit"> Acessar Papel  - QM 
   </button>
            </form>
```

Comment: Olá, você não está escrevendo $loc nem $ori no "select option", apenas na consulta SQL, então o click do botão não vai agir neles. Se quer guardar essas duas variáveis e enviar mais uma por GET ao clicar no botão, adicione as variáveis no "select option" ou salve elas em SESSION

Comment: para poder enviar juntamente com o form, você precisa coloca-las em campos do formulário, eles podem ser escondidos, por exemplo tente utilizar dois campos escondidos dentro do seu `<form>`:  `<input name=loc type=hidden value="<?php echo $_GET['loc'];?>"` e `<input name=ori type=hidden value="<?php echo $_GET['ori'];?>"` e resgata-los com GET

Comment: @PauloRoberto, Da sua forma funcionou, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione dois inputs hidden no seu formulário com os valores recebidos via GET da outra pagina

```
<input type="hidden" name="loc" value="<?php echo $loc ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="ori" value="<?php echo $ori ?>">
```

**Pagina do formulário**

```
<form class="got" method="GET" action="real_time.qm.php">
   <select name="papel">
<?php
  //Recebo as variaveis da outra pagina
  $loc = $_GET['loc'];
  $ori = $_GET['ori'];

  include ("Conectcma.php");

    $pl = "SELECT Papel FROM reg_qm_papel WHERE Local = '$loc' AND origem = '$ori'";
    $plgo = mysqli_query($conexao, $pl);

    while($sc_l = mysqli_fetch_array($plgo)){
      echo '<option>'.$sc_l['Papel'].'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>

<input type="hidden" name="loc" value="<?php echo $loc ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="ori" value="<?php echo $ori ?>">

 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <button class="css_btn_class" type="submit"> Acessar Papel  - QM</button>
</form>
```

**Na pagina `real_time.qm.php` resgate os valores passados via GET**

```
$loc = $_GET['loc'];
$ori = $_GET['ori'];
$papel = $_GET['papel'];
```

---

> Também poderia anexar os valores recuperados via GET no action do formulário e enviar o valor do select via POST:

```
<form class="got" method="POST" action="real_time.qm.php?loc=<?php echo $_GET['loc'] ?>&ori=<?php echo $_GET['ori'] ?>">
```

pagina `real_time.qm.php`

```
$loc = $_GET['loc'];
$ori = $_GET['ori'];
$papel = $_POST['papel'];
```

Comment: Faltou o "exemplo funcional" euhaeuh :D

Comment: @ÐvÐ pronto, seu pedido foi atendido, huauhuahuah

Comment: :D e dessa vez em dose dupla rs

Answer (score 1):

**USANDO SESSÃO**

No começo do arquivo PHP adicione

```
session_start();
```

Crie um vetor com $loc e $ori e salve em SESSION:

```
$dados = array(
    "local" => $loc,
    "origem" => $ori
);
$_SESSION["localOrigem"] = $dados;
```

Na página onde deseja recuperar as 3 variáveis você inicia a sessão, dá um **GET** ou **POST** no "name" do *select* e recupera o vetor da sessão:

```
session_start();
$doFormulario = $_GET["name_do_select"]; //coloque o nome do select
$variaveis_loc_e_ori = $_SESSION["localOrigem"];
//pronto, a variável do form está em cima e a loc e ori em baixo
```

Comment: Jhonatan, o mySqli não foi depreciado, foi o `mysql_`, sem `i`, leia isto: [**Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/3635). Outra coisa, depreciado não é o termo correto, na verdade é um erro comum dos programadores associarem a palavra em inglês que tem um significado diferente, leia isto: [**O que é um código depreciado?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178138/3635)

Comment: Ah sim, falha minha kk Obrigado pela observação.

Comment: Recomendo que mude o código de volta pra mysqli, pois não há necessidade do autor usar PDO, ele já começou em mysqli mesmo.

Comment: não entendi para que serve esse name no option

Comment: Pra você pegar o valor do option no PHP... $_GET['nameDoOption'];

Comment: Devem ser vários options pois são gerados dentro de um while. Não seria pegar o valor do option pelo name do select? $_GET['papel'];

Comment: Oops, verdade, confundi. O select leva o "name" e os "option" levam o "value"