# Tomcat - RFC 7230 and RFC 3986

Tags: java, apache, java-ee, http, tomcat

Estou com um problema de : Error parsing HTTP request header
Meu servidor apache tomcat 8 está rejeitando as requisições de um sistema o qual eu fiz uma integração, o erro é por conta de caracteres que está na requisição, estava dando uma olhada e vi que existia o :

```
 tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser. requestTargetAllow
```

Não obtive sucesso utilizando este atributo.

Observei que ele é considerado obsoleto e que agora tem

```
relaxedPathChars and relaxedQueryChars
```

utilizado no Connector do tomcat porém não consigo achar exemplo funcional dos mesmos e não sei como usa-lós no connector, já tentei utiliza-los e não obtive sucesso. Preciso ou de um exemplo funcional desses atributos ou de alguma alternativa, eu preciso aceitar essa requisição de qualquer forma. Preciso de uma luz!

Comment: Reverti para a edição do Bacco, **depreciado** não é tradução de **Deprecated**, a tradução correta aproximada é «obsoleto», «desuso» ou «desencorajado»  (existem mais). Isso ai é erro de um pessoal que acabou virando algo comum, - leia: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178138/3635

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma: 
Editar o arquivo catalina.properties que está dentro da pasta conf/ do tomcat.
No final do arquivo adicionar as seguintes linhas :

```
tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow=|{} 

org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true
```

Agora o tomcat passou aceitar tranquilamente.