# Como resolver um problema de each() depreciado?

Tags: php

Meu código

```
elseif (is_array($image)) {
        list($key, $width) = each($image);
        list($key, $height) = each($image); 

        $image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

    }
```

Esse trecho está aparcendo um Notice de each depreciado. Como resolver?

Comment: [depreciado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178138/o-que-%c3%a9-um-c%c3%b3digo-depreciado#comment368172_178138)

Comment: _Deprecated_ é um falso cognato, como muitas palavras em inglês. Por exemplo, a palavra _library_ dá impressão que é "livraria", mas significa "biblioteca" (totalmente diferente). O termo "depreciado" significa algo que foi diminuído de valor ou de preço, o que é bem diferente de "obsoleto", que seria a tradução mais apropriada.

Answer (score 2):

**Não é necessário `foreach`** para executar uma operação **tão simples** que pode ser escrito, se imagem é um array de 2 valores (provavelmente mais, e provavelmente usou `getimagesize`), se tem isto:

```
array(7) {
   [0]=> int(2048) 
   [1]=> int(852) 
   [2]=> int(2) 
   [3]=> string(25) "width="2048" height="852"" 
   ["bits"]=> int(8) 
   ["channels"]=> int(3) 
   ["mime"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg"
}
```

Basta setar diretamente:

```
$width = $image[0]; //0 é o indice da largura
$height = $image[1]; //1 é o indice da largura

$image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
```

Uma nota extra, como eu já [comentei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178138/o-que-%C3%A9-um-c%C3%B3digo-depreciado#comment368172_178138) em outra publicação:

> ... «depreciado» é a tradução errada e esta sendo mal usada e confundida com a palavra correta, «depreciado» em inglês é «depreciated» e não «deprecated». A palavra «deprecated» que seria a correta para se referir a isto seria traduzida como «obsoleto», «desaprovado», «censurado». No caso de uso aqui o melhor com certeza é «obsoleto». Resumindo «depreciado» e «depreciated» nada tem haver com isto

Comment: Obrigado pela aula de português e pela ajuda.

Answer (score -2):

Resolvi

```
foreach($image as $key=>$v){
            ($key == 0) ? $width = $v : $height = $v;
        }
        $image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
```