# Como criar botão de copiar com javascript mas sem input ou textarea

Tags: javascript, java, html

Eu precisava a criar um botão que copiasse o número de pedido que retorna. O script já funciona com a tag textarea, mas eu precisava que funcionasse com code (que já uso) ou p. Pelo que posso substuir textarea?

```html
 <strong>N° do pedido</strong>:<code textcopy><h5><b style="color: #A8061A;">{{ order['id'] }}</b></h5></code>
                                                
    <button onclick="copyToClipBoard()" i class="fa fa-search"></button>
                                            
                     <script>

                        function copyToClipBoard() {
         var content = document.getElementById('textcopy');
                         content.select();                  
document.execCommand('copy')
             alert("Copied!");
                                    }
                                   </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o código abaixo deva funcionar. Sugiro que teste o código abaixo no **próprio ambiente da sua máquina**, pois ao executar no **strack overflow** ele mostra um **erro de permissão**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Também tentei no **JSFiddle**, mas logicamente como é algo **relacionado a permissão** em relação ao **acesso ao clipboard** (área de transferência do domínio), ele também aparece o mesmo erro.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Aqui estão minhas referências** caso queira verificar antes de testar:

[delftstack javascript-copy-to-clipboard](https://www.delftstack.com/pt/howto/javascript/javascript-copy-to-clipboard/)

[w3schools howto_js_copy_clipboard](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp)

**OBS.:** Para verificar o erro inspecione o código pelo stackoverflow e aqui está o link do **JSFiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/gutobr9/tynL4m6c/15/ onde pode conferir o erro no console do próprio **JSFiddle**

```js
 function copyToClickBoard(){
    var content = document.getElementById('dado').innerHTML;

    navigator.clipboard.writeText(content)
    //     .then(() => {
    //     console.log("Text copied to clipboard...")
    // })
    //     .catch(err => {
    //     console.log('Something went wrong', err);
    // })
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="dado">!!Aperte em copiar para copiar esse texto!!</p>
  <button onclick="copyToClickBoard()">Copiar</button>
  <br><br>
  <input />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Como o comando **document.execCommand** está depreciado, segundo o [w3schools document.execCommand](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_execcommand.asp), recomendo procurar usar o comando: **navigator.clipboard.writeText**, referenciada  acima.

Comment: [Depreciado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178138/o-que-%C3%A9-um-c%C3%B3digo-depreciado#comment368172_178138)